# Python preencher valores com dados de outras linhas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Bom dia, estou com um grande problema de falha de dados no meu `df`. Preciso encontrar o valor de CO2 parecido com o de outro horário utilizando condições que não estou conseguindo fazer com as informações da linha. Possuo um `df` de `1` ano com valores de `30 em 30 minutos`. os valores de Temperatura e Radiação não possuem faltantes, apenas tenho valores faltantes no `CO2`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_hdf('./dados.hd5')

df.head()

Year_DoY_Hour          Temperatura    radiacao        CO2
2016-01-01 00:00:00    22.44570        0              380
2016-01-01 00:30:00    22.445700       0              390 
.
.
2016-01-15 00:00:00    22.88300        0              379
2016-01-15 00:30:00    22.445700       0              381 
2016-01-15 01:00:00    22.388300       0              NaN
.
.
.
2016-01-30 00:00:00    22.400000       0              350       
2016-01-30 00:30:00    16.393900       0              375                
2016-01-30 01:00:00    17.133900       0              365
```

- (a)Temperatura deve estar entre `+- 2.5ºC`;
- (b)Radiação `+- 50W/m²`;
- Tenho que ter uma janela de `-+ 3 dias` entre o valor com `NaN` de `CO2`.
- Calcular a média dos valores de `CO2` quando `(a)` e `(b)` forem aceitas na condição e colocar onde tenho o dado faltante de `CO2`.

No `df` apresentado acima temos que para o dia e horário `2016-01-15 01:00:00` temos `NaN` no `CO2` e então não consigo encontrar uma Temp. e radia. para preencher o valor de `CO2`. 
Acredito que com condições eu consigo fazer, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Olá! Sua pergunta não foi muito clara. Você quer poder ler o seu arquivo e tratar uma exceção quando a leitura encontrar o `NaN`?

Comment: Olá! Isso mesmo, quando encontrar `NaN` no `CO2` ele pega naquele mesmo horário a temperatura e radiação e procura nos últimos 3 dias e nos próximos valores parecidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Cria um index dos valores que são Nan
nan_index = df[df.isnull()].index
# Para todos os Nans
for i in range(df.isnull().sum()):
    # Extrai os valores da outra coluna que você quer procurar
    dado_nan = df[['coluna']][df.isnull()].iloc[i].values()
    # Substitui com as médias dos valores dentro da faixa desejada
    df['novaColuna'][nan_index[i]] = df[abs(df.coluna - dado_nan[0]) < 2.5].mean()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Lucas, esse processo chama-se [`interpolação`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Como seus dados estão no formato de `dataframe`, dê uma olhada no [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html). E dê uma olhada também na parte que fala sobre [Como Trabalhar com Dados Faltantes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#interpolation).

De acordo com o docs, tente rodar o comando:

```
df['CO2'].interpolate()
```

Também pode definir qual o método de interpolação a ser utilizado:

```
method : {‘linear’, ‘time’, ‘index’, ‘values’, ‘nearest’, ‘zero’,
‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘barycentric’, ‘krogh’, ‘polynomial’, ‘spline’, ‘piecewise_polynomial’, ‘from_derivatives’, ‘pchip’, ‘akima’}
```

Ex.:

```
df['CO2'].interpolate(method='linear')]
```

Além disso, você também pode incorporar cláusulas condicionais para interpolar obedecendo determinadas condições.

Comment: Este método já fiz, mas agora preciso fazer com essas condições que escrevi acima.